# Как спарсить html код который весь в тексте без тегов?

Tags: php, html, phpquery

```
<p class="dop-info">
<strong>Дата публикации:</strong> 08.07.16 20:17<br>
<strong>Категория:</strong> выпечка<br>
<strong>Время приготовления:</strong> 1 час 30 минут <br>
</p>
```

Как спарсить данный текст таким образом чтобы получить не Категория: а сам текст.

допустим отлько 1 час 30 минут

Надо парсить в phpQuery

Comment: Что-то вроде `$str = preg_replace('#(< strong.*?> ).*?(< /strong> )#', '$1$2', $str);`

Comment: на js/jquery не надо?

Comment: ` 1 час 30 минут ` тоже в тэге.

Comment: Чем парсите-то?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin,Надо парсить в phpQuery

Comment: @Nick, можно в phpQuery? я хочу принцип понять чтобы остальные теги парсить.